# How do you handle native module errors in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, error-handling

so I have transitioned to react native recently from react and the web, one thing I am struggling with is understand native errors and how to handle them. For example, one error logging to bugsnag is `Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x18.` Is this fixable from my side, how do you go generally go about native module errors in react native?

Looking for practises / advice.